(mgks/Android-SmartWebView) Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag
I am a total newbie and I have cloned a repo (WebView app) from https://github.com/mgks/Android-SmartWebView.git. to test my website but when i try to run, it gives an error "Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag."
Although i have added "FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK" in the Intent the error won't go away.I have been trying to solve it since last night but to vain. Someone Please guide me.
Thank you.
// opening URLs inside webview with request
void aswm_view(String url, Boolean tab, int error_counter, Context context) {
    if (error_counter > 2) {
        exit_app(context);
    } else {
        if (tab) {
            if (SmartWebView.ASWP_TAB) {
                CustomTabsIntent.Builder intentBuilder = new CustomTabsIntent.Builder();
                intentBuilder.setStartAnimations(context.getApplicationContext(), android.R.anim.slide_in_left, android.R.anim.slide_out_right);
                intentBuilder.setExitAnimations(context.getApplicationContext(), android.R.anim.slide_in_left, android.R.anim.slide_out_right);
                CustomTabsIntent customTabsIntent = intentBuilder.build();
                try {
                    customTabsIntent.launchUrl(context.getApplicationContext(), Uri.parse(url));
                } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    intent.setData(Uri.parse(url));
                    context.startActivity(intent);
                }
            } else {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                intent.setData(Uri.parse(url));
                context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        } else {
            // check to see whether the url already has query parameters and handle appropriately
            url = url + (url.contains("?")


                ? "&" : "?") + "rid=" + random_id();
            SmartWebView.asw_view.loadUrl(url);
        }
    }
}

The Error :
FATAL EXCEPTION: main                                                                                       
Process: mgks.os.swv, PID: 19610                                                                                          
android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?                                                                                               at android.app.ContextImpl.startActivity(ContextImpl.java:1127)                                                                                          
at android.content.ContextWrapper.startActivity(ContextWrapper.java:458)                                                                                         
at androidx.core.content.ContextCompat$Api16Impl.startActivity(ContextCompat.java:978)                                                                                               
at androidx.core.content.ContextCompat.startActivity(ContextCompat.java:318)                                                                                             
at androidx.browser.customtabs.CustomTabsIntent.launchUrl(CustomTabsIntent.java:483)                                                                                             
at mgks.os.swv.Functions.aswm_view(Functions.java:88)                                                                                                
at mgks.os.swv.Functions.url_actions(Functions.java:170)                                                                                             
at mgks.os.swv.MainActivity$Callback.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(MainActivity.java:641)                                                                                                 
at 
org.chromium.android_webview.AwContentsClientBridge.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(chromium- 
TrichromeWebViewGoogle6432.apk-stable-567263637:89)                                                                                              
at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)                                                                                                 
at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:335)                                                                                               
at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:162)                                                                                               
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:294)                                                                                           
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8177)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)                                                                                                
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:552)                                                                                                 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:971)


have you tried to startActivity from context.getApplicationContext(), not straight from context?
